# How to find where a function was imported from in Python?

Tags: python, module

I have a Python module with a function in it:

```
  == bar.py ==
  def foo(): pass
  == EOF ==
```

And then I import it into the global namespace like so:

```
from bar import *
```

So now the function `foo` is available to me. If I print it:

```
print foo
```

The interpreter happily tells me:

```
 <function foo at 0xb7eef10c>
```

Is there a way for me to find out that function `foo` came from module `bar` at this point?

Comment: Why are you using `from bar import *`?  Why do this?  This specific syntax is what causes your problem, so why do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`foo.__module__` should return `bar`

If you need more info, you can get it from `sys.modules['bar']`, its `__file__` and `__package__` attributes may be interesting.

Comment: This __package__ attribute is really cool, but seems to be unavailable. Is it available in python 2.5.2?

Comment: Ah no, it seems new in Python 2.6: http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-366-explicit-relative-imports-from-a-main-module

Comment: Ok, so I researched the __package__ thing a bit. What I can't tell is whether the value is added by default, or if I have to specify something. I tried importing an empty module ("z.xx"), and z.xx.__package__ returned None. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure, I can't seem to get it set either. It seems the `runpy` module is the only one actually using it. What information did you hope to get from it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
help(foo.func_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
from bar import *
```

use

```
from bar import foo
```

Using the `from ... import *` syntax is a bad programming style precisely because it makes it hard to know where elements of your namespace come from.

Comment: +1 because this is a valid point, although it may not solve the problem (if the questioner wants to know where the function came from programmatically, having `from bar import foo` is basically the same)

Answer (score 0):

If you have IPython, you can also use `?`:

```
In[16]: runfile?
Signature: runfile(filename, args=None, wdir=None, is_module=False, global_vars=None)
Docstring:
Run filename
args: command line arguments (string)
wdir: working directory
File:      /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py
Type:      function
```

Compare with `__module__`:

```
In[17]:  runfile.__module__
Out[17]: '_pydev_bundle.pydev_umd'
```