# Load one function but cannot load another in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python file with two functions in it:

```
== bar.py ==
  def foo1(): pass
  def foo2(): pass
== EOF ==
```

And then I import it into the global namespace like so:

```
from bar import *
```

So both functions `foo1` and `foo2` should be available to me. If I try to print each one:

```
print(foo1)
```

then the interpreter happily tells me it's there:

```
<function foo1 at 0x7fd6e489fcf8>
```

But then I try to print the second one:

```
print(foo2)
```

And I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'foo2' is not defined
```

What are some possible causes of this? Could this be, for example, if `foo1` was written in Python 3 syntax and `foo2` was written in Python 2 syntax? What else could it be?

NOTE: thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730466/how-to-find-where-a-function-was-imported-from-in-python), which I used for formatting this question.

EDIT: Here's another version of `bar.py`, as requested in a comment:

```
def foo1():
    pass

def foo2():
    pass
```

Comment: Copy and paste the bar.py to question without formatting. `NameError: name 'foo2' is not defined` does mean that function `foo2()` does not exist.

Comment: I suspect indentation problems in `bar.py`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that file.

Comment: Do you have more than one `bar.py` lying around?

Comment: Psychic debugging attempt - you have another `bar.py` you're importing, or you forgot to save it after adding `foo2`.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same with the other version? Because that error for me is non-reproducible

Answer (score 0):

This might occur if another version of bar.py exists in a filesystem path that is listed in your PYTHONPATH before the bar.py you are actually editing.  The python interpreter will use the first bar.py it finds in the python path, after the current working folder of course.

Comment: This _might_ be the answer.

Comment: Well certainly, which is why I did not say "this will ONLY occur".  It is a possible answer.  I changed the wording as such.